# Puppet vs Ansible - why would organisation use both?

Tags: ansible, puppet

I have worked in an organisation where we used both puppet and ansible for configuration management... but I always wondered why would they use both tools ... what can puppet do that Ansible cannot do?

The only thought that came to my mind was:
- Puppet was used to check if the system is in the desired state at regular intervals; while Ansible was used to deploy one time things (code, scripts, packages etc)

Can someone please explain why would an organisation use both the tools? Can regular config check be done by Ansible?

Cheers

Comment: *"Can regular config check be done by Ansible?"* - Something the docs would tell you. *"Can someone please explain why would an organisation use both the tools?"* - Mainly solliciting opinions, and off topic for that reason.

Comment: Ansible is primarily an orchestration/deployment tool. Puppet is primarily a configuration management/software provisioning tool. That is why many companies use them together.

Answer (score 21):

In the interest of full disclosure, I'm an upstream community contributing developer to Ansible but I will do my best to keep my response neutral.

I think this is largely opinionated and you'll get varied results depending on who you talk to but I think about it effectively like this:

Ansible is an automation tool and Puppet is a configuration management tool. I don't consider them to be direct competitors they way they seem to get compared by tech journalists except for the fact that there's some overlap in their abilities to perform the functions you would want out of a configuration management tool: service/system state, configuration file templating, application lifecycle management, etc.

The main place where I see these tools in completely different light is that Ansible performs automation of tasks, those tasks can be one of *many* "type" of things that you don't really expect from a configuration management tool, such as IaaS provisioning (AWS, GCE, Azure, RAX, Linode, etc), physical network configuration (Cisco IOS/ASA, JunOS, Arista, VyOS, Netscaler, etc), virtual machine creation/management, physical load balancer configuration (F5 BigIP) and the list goes on. Effectively, Ansible is your "automation glue" to create and automate a process that you and your team might have otherwise had to do by hand. It as a tool gets compared to things like Puppet, Chef, and SaltStack because one of the many "types" of task you would automate more or less add up to configuration management.

On the flip side though Configuration Management tools such as Puppet generally have a daemon running on the nodes, which needs to be provisioned/bootstrapped (maybe with Ansible), which has it's advantages and disadvantages (which I won't debate here, it's largely out of scope). One thing that daemon provides you is continuous eventual consistency. You can set configuration management authoritatively on the Puppet Master and then the agent will maintain that state on the systems and will provide reporting when it has to change something which can be wired up to alert monitoring to notify you when something's wrong. While Ansible will also report when something needed changing, it only does this when you run the Ansible Playbook. It's a push-model and not pull-model (nor is it a continuously running daemon that will enforce system state). This has it's advantages for reporting and the like. I will note that something like Ansible Tower/AWX can more or less emulate this functionality, but it's not a "baked in" feature. Just something to keep in mind.

Ultimately, I think it boils down to a matter of familiarity of technologies, desired feature set, and if you have a pre-existing investment (both time and money) into a toolchain. If you have been using Puppet for 5 years, there's no real motivation to fork-lift replace it with something else when you can use Ansible to augment it (there's even a puppet module in Ansible) and allow each to play nicely with each other, getting the features you want from both. However, if you're starting from scratch, then I think you may consider actually doing a Pros/Cons or feature comparison for what you really want out of the tool(s) to find out if it's worth the investment of picking up two tools from scratch or finding one that can fulfill all your needs and, while I'm biased towards Ansible in this regard, the choice ultimately lies on the person who's going to have to use the utility to maintain the infrastructure.

I think a good example of the hybrid approach is I know of a few companies that use Puppet for configuration management, and Ansible for software lifecycle release process where one of the tasks in their playbooks is literally calling the puppet module to bring all the systems into configuration consistency. The Ansible component in this is to automate/orchestrate between various systems, the basic outline of the process is this: start with removing a group of hosts from the load balancer, ensure database connections have stopped, perform upgrades/migrations, run puppet for configuration/state consistency, and then bring things back online in whatever order they've deemed appropriate. This all happens from a single command (or a click of a button in Tower/AWX).

Anyhoo, I know that was kind of long winded but hopefully it was helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Adam ... How relevant is Puppet or any Configuration Management in general in a more dynamic cloud environment as VMs are created and deleted continuously? To make it more complex, containerized environment? - Do we need that configuration state which Puppet is primarily used for especially when we have light VMs using fully baked images or microservices running in a machine (LXC/LXD) or application (docker) containers?

Comment: Personally? I think "traditional configuration management" will slowly fade away as the types of workflows you describe become pervasive and you not longer need configuration management, but instead you need something more flexible for automation of all kinds of tasks. (I think Puppet Labs has even come around as they now have a direct competitor to Ansible called Bolt that's a similar design)